# Clickable QLabel class "multiply defined" functions

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having trouble moving from VC++ to Qt-style programming with slots/signals. I wanted to create a button with an image that, when clicked, changed to another image, and when released, changed back to its original. I created a class called `ClickableQLabel` that inherits from QLabel, but it's telling me that certain functions are re-defined. Specifically, the ones that are `emit`ted.

MainProgram.cpp

```
#include "MainProgram.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    CodeVault w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

MainProgram.h

```
#ifndef MAINPROGRAM_H
#define MAINPROGRAM_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "clickableqlabel.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainProgram;
}

class MainProgram : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainProgram(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainProgram();

private:
    Ui::MainProgram *ui;
};

#endif // MAINPROGRAM_H
```

clickableqlabel.h

```
#ifndef CLICKABLEQLABEL_H
#define CLICKABLEQLABEL_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QMouseEvent>

using namespace Qt;

class ClickableQLabel : public QLabel {
    Q_OBJECT
    QPixmap pushed;
    QPixmap unpushed;
public:
    ClickableQLabel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *eve );
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *eve );
    void setPushed(QPixmap &p);
    void setUnpushed(QPixmap &p);

signals:
    void leftButtonPressed(ClickableQLabel* sender);
    void leftButtonReleased(ClickableQLabel* sender);
};

#endif // CLICKABLEQLABEL_H
```

clickableqlabel.cpp

```
#include "clickableqlabel.h"

ClickableQLabel::ClickableQLabel(QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent){
    // set up qlabel
}


void ClickableQLabel::setPushed(QPixmap &p){
    pushed = p;
}

void ClickableQLabel::setUnpushed(QPixmap &p){
    unpushed = p;
}

void ClickableQLabel::leftButtonPressed(ClickableQLabel* sender){
    if(!pushed.isNull())
        sender->setPixmap(pushed.scaledToWidth(sender->width()));
}

void ClickableQLabel::leftButtonReleased(ClickableQLabel* sender){
    if(!unpushed.isNull())
        sender->setPixmap(unpushed.scaledToWidth(sender->width()));
}

void ClickableQLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *eve ){
    if(eve->button() == Qt::LeftButton){
        emit leftButtonPressed(this);
    }
}

void ClickableQLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *eve ){
    if(eve->button() == Qt::LeftButton){
        emit leftButtonReleased(this);
    }
}
```

What I receive is the following 3 errors:

```
moc_clickableqlabel.obj:-1: error: LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl ClickableQLabel::leftButtonPressed(class ClickableQLabel *)" (?leftButtonPressed@ClickableQLabel@@QEAAXPEAV1@@Z) already defined in clickableqlabel.obj
moc_clickableqlabel.obj:-1: error: LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl ClickableQLabel::leftButtonReleased(class ClickableQLabel *)" (?leftButtonReleased@ClickableQLabel@@QEAAXPEAV1@@Z) already defined in clickableqlabel.obj
debug\CodeVault.exe:-1: error: LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

The two functions that are causing the errors are the two signals in the clickableqlabel.h file. How am I supposed to set up the `connect` function and where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't provide an implementation for your signals. You just declare signals in the class header. the Qt moc provides an implementation that is responsible to call the slots `connect`ed to the signal when it is emitted, see [this](https://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html). Because you are providing an implementation and Qt moc is providing another one, you end up with two different implementations and the linker complains.

so, to make some piece of code execute when a signal is emitted, you can put it in some slot that is connected to that signal, or you can execute it manually before emitting the signal. . .

Another thing to note is that your signals have a parameter named `sender`. normally there is no need to do this, [`QObject::sender()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) provides similar functionality.

> How am I supposed to set up the connect function and where?

When you  instantiate your `ClickableQLabel` in your `MainProgram` window for example (You can do this by using `ClickableQLabel` in a `.ui` form file), you can `connect` its signals to slots of the `MainProgram`, like this.

mainprogram.h

```
#ifndef MAINPROGRAM_H
#define MAINPROGRAM_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "clickableqlabel.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainProgram;
}

class MainProgram : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainProgram(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainProgram();
public slots:
    void labelPressed();
    void labelReleased();
private:
    Ui::MainProgram *ui;
};

#endif // MAINPROGRAM_H
```

then in the constructor `connect` the `ClickableQLabel`'s signals to the `MainProgram`'s slots , something like this:

```
connect(clickableLabel, SIGNAL(leftButtonPressed()), this, SLOT(labelPressed()));
```

where `clickableLabel` is your `ClickableQLabel` object.

Comment: In modern C++/Qt, you really shouldn't need `sender()`, lambdas do that job admirably unless you're on some sort of a red-hot path where every instruction counts.

Comment: Interesting solution. Thank you for providing the code as well. Thanks!

Comment: of course,  you can use lambdas they end up with more readable code. I am  just used to the old style. . .

Comment: Accepted as the answer because it's easy to implement, works with what I already have, is easy to understand, and is applicable to other scenarios that were bringing up similar issues. Thanks again!

Comment: You don't have to call `qRegisterMetaType` unless you are using queued connections.

Comment: You can either remove it, or just point out that it is only needed for queued connections, though I don't think that it has any significance in this context.

Comment: @thuga , ok, I removed it :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not explicitly define signal "functions" - they are simply emitted (as you do in the `mousePressEvent()` and `mouseReleaseEvent()` functions).

If you want some action performed (such as setPixmap), you would either do that in the slot functions that are connected to those signals, or perhaps directly in the `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` functions.

Unrelated, but you may also need to do something like `qRegisterMetaType<ClickableQLabel>()` to use that data type with the signal/slot mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to subclass `QLabel` to achieve this: put an `onLabelButtonClicked` slot (method) in your `MainWindow` class, which is connected to the `QPushButton` `clicked()` signal, and which calls setText / setIcon as required.

If you want to re-use this clickable element you can of course encapsulate it in a class, but subclassing and handling raw-events is only required in Qt when defining new kinds of widget; if you're simply composing standard functionality (being clicked, adjusting appearance) then slots on your main window / dialog class are usually sufficient.

Comment: `QLabel` does NOT emit signals when clicked. So, if we wanted to handle mouse press events on it, we have to subclass it, there is  a similar example [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Clickable_QLabel).

Comment: @Mike He never claimed it did. He suggested to use `QPushButton`.